# jQuery Animate Working in Chrome but not Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am using the following JavaScript:

```
$('#sidebar-wrapper').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: '250px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('.container').animate({ paddingLeft: '260px' }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: '35px' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('.container').animate({ paddingLeft: '40px' }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    }).trigger('mouseleave');
```

It works in Chrome, but doesn't work in IE. How can i fix this?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? According to https://code.jquery.com/ version 2.x does not support versions of IE less than 9.

Comment: Also, do you get any errors in IE? What IE version?

Comment: using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js and IE11

Comment: OK. False alarm. IE was loading one of my JS files from cache. How do i disable caching for pages and JS files ?

Comment: Hi,
I wrote a website and include JS files like this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/app.js"></script>

Chrome loads all files correctly and website displayed correctly
IE doesn't load all JS and css files (part are loaded and part are not). resulting in website not displayed correctly. 
part of computers display correctly the website (in IE) and part not. 
IE version in all computers is 11